# Message type "caffe.LayerParameter" has no field named "input_param"

Tags: caffe, pycaffe

I downloaded the latest caffe library today and build.

Tested the library in python to run through a classification program in Python.

In parsing the prototxt file, I have the error as `Message type "caffe.LayerParameter" has no field named "input_param"`.

The error happened at `net = caffe.Net(model_def, model_weights, caffe.TEST`) .

```
.model_def = caffe_root + 'models/bvlc_reference_caffenet/deploy.prototxt'
 model_weights = caffe_root + 'models/bvlc_reference_caffenet/bvlc_reference_caffenet.caffemodel'

 net = caffe.Net(model_def,      # defines the structure of the model
                model_weights,  # contains the trained weights
                caffe.TEST)     # use test mode (e.g., don't perform dropout)
```

According to the discussion [here](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/3947), the error is because of not using latest build.
For me I used the latest build. How to fix the issue.

Comment: make sure your `$PYTHONPATH` points to the new build and that you indeed work with the correct version of caffe.

Comment: You mean in the ./bashrc or which $PYTHONPATH?

Comment: I have sys.path.insert(0, caffe_root + 'python'), so it includes the path in run time.